# what is the correct way, to log or to throw error in cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am sorry if this question is too basic, since I am a beginner in backend programming and cloud function. so I want to know what the correct way to show the error in firebase console. here is my function

```
exports.firestoreTriggerUpdateCreatedEvent = functions.firestore.document('events/{eventId}').onUpdate(async (change,context) => {

    // to also edit event data in createdEvents in user(creator) subcollection

    try {

        const newCreatedEventData = change.after.data()
        const eventID = context.params.eventId
        const creatorID = newCreatedEventData.createdBy

        return db.doc(`users/${creatorID}/createdEvents/${eventID}`).set(newCreatedEventData)

    } catch(error) {
        throw new Error(`Failed: ${error}`)
    }

})
```

some people will throw error like my code above, but I also see it just log the error

```
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

so whats the correct way to throw or just log the error ? as I know it will affect the log level in firebase console

[image]

I actually prefer to throw the error, because I think it will make me easier to trace because of that red icon.

if i just console.log(error). will it appear on the health tab ?
[image]

but I don't know, maybe there is something to be considered ?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct since each one have it’s own purpose.
By throwing the exception, we allow the caller to handle it, and by logging, we can identify the root cause of it ourself.

There are 4 ways to [log in cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs):

- `console.log()`
- `console.info()`
- `console.warn()`
- `console.error()`

And it would depend on your codes logic which one you use in each event.